# Forum to talk about remote job salaries

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

What is the correct forum in Stack Exchange to talk about salaries in the remote jobs? Because Stack Overflow is just to tech questions, right?

Comment: Also, Stack Exchange sites are Q&A sites, not discussion forums. There's a big difference. Please be sure to read the site [tour] to understand more about the difference.

Comment: Can you expand on your question? I wonder if it needs to be rewritten to ask what you wanted to ask about, rather than asking where you can ask it?

Answer (score 6):

I believe...unless you have received a job offer from a company advertising on Jobs with a salary that was *radically* different than what was posted (e.g. they promised $70,000 for a junior position with 0-2 years experience, and they made you an offer for $36,000), you **are not** able to discuss remote job salaries, since *everything* would be subjective and up to speculation.

And even if that *had* happened, it'd be best to [shoot the support team an email](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f) instead of discussing it on Meta.